# Radiated power from a straight conducting wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, maxwell-equations

Consider an infinite long straight conducting wire with an oscillating current inside. The current is assumed to be uniform over the cross-section of the wire. The resistance per unit length is given by $$R_s=\frac{\rho}{A},$$ with $\rho$ the resistivity and $A$ the area of the cross-section of the wire.

The oscillating magnetic field around the wire, $H=\frac{I}{2\pi R}e^{i\omega t}$, generates electromagnetic waves and thus also power is lost via this radiation mechanism. Why is this radiation resistance $R_\mathrm{rad}$ not considered when writing the resistance of a wire? Is this negligibly small compared to the series resistance $R_s$ of the wire? Or is the radiated power captured in the resistivity $\rho$?

Is there an equation to calculate the emitted power (via electromagnetic radiation) per unit length of a straight wire?

Comment: I understand that this radiation loss is the reason some companies use DC current for long distance power transmission.

Comment: Can we assume  that only the real component of your oscillating function is significant?

Comment: The oscillating function is just the Oersted field around the wire. The real part is significant.